# Newbie navigation quesions

Tags: navigation, 3d-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Few questions about navigation:

1: I have recently read about point cloud to laser scan 2D conversion of data. I already have kinect and 2D Hokuyo mounted on my robot. Does that mean I can completely avoid LADAR and use Kinect instead? To perform, experiments such as mapping, navigation planning.

2: Since Navigation requires accurate odometory data how can we work in case of any hardware wear and tear. For e.g: In case I have two motors of same configuration. After using it for some period there might be some wear and tear in such case how odometory behaves?

3.Can i use **ONLY** Kinect for mapping and navigation without IMU or 2D laser scanner?
OR can i combine the data of Kinect and Laser scanner using Kalman filter? (NO IMU)

Any Help appreciated,

Abhimoh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44573/newbie-navigation-quesions/) by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2012-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Yes, but I'd highly advise against that. The Kinect data is far worse for 2D navigation.
2. If it's not too bad, and the error covariances are correct, algorithms should be able to cope with that.
3. You can use http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_matcher to provide fake odometry from laser data. Alternately, http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping should work without odometry.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0